Unable to build pySFML - 'Time' is not a type identifier
I'm unsuccessfully trying to build pySFML from https://github.com/intjelic/python-sfml on my Windows machine with Python 3.12 (aswell as 3.11, 3.10, 3.9).
I have downloaded SFML 2.3.2 from https://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.3.2/ and have Visual Studio 22 installed.
After extracting SFML-2.3.2 to C:\libraries, i have set the Environment-Variables:
SFML_DIR       = C:\libraries\SFML-2.3.2
SFML_HEADERS   = C:\libraries\SFML-2.3.2\include
SFML_LIBRARIES = C:\libraries\SFML-2.3.2\lib

and added to Path:
C:\libraries\SFML-2.3.2\bin

I then git-cloned the repo https://github.com/intjelic/python-sfml.git into a Python 3.12 venv.
And installed the requirements:
pip install -r requirements.txt

(which installed Cython-Version 3.0.10)
after that I did:
pip install --upgrade setuptools wheel

When I then at first tried:
pip install .

I got:
Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...

      from libcpp.string cimport string

      cimport time
              ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------

      include\Includes\sfml\sfml.pxd:9:8: 'time.pxd' not found

but the file is in the directory and there is also a empty init.py file, but anyways I changed it to:
from . cimport Time

It now finds the file but I get:
Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...

      from sfml cimport Time

      cdef extern from "SFML/System.hpp" namespace "sf::Time":
          cdef Time Zero
               ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------

      include\Includes\sfml\Time.pxd:10:9: 'Time' is not a type identifier

The actual traceback is much longer (the same as above for every other class) and can be seen here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ai-cr/pySFML-traceback/main/pySFML_traceback.txt
I understand that the project is no longer maintainend, but shouldn't a specific release with a specific python/cython version work, as it worked in the past?
Did anyone manage to install pySFML? Help would be much appreciated..!

It looks like it was last updated 4 years ago. That would be a Cython 0.29.x release probably. Before that the previous update was 7 years ago which would be about Cython 0.27.x. I expect 0.29.x will work but Cython 3 has made larger incompatible changes. The last builds on their pipeline suggest Python 3.8: https://github.com/intjelic/python-sfml/blob/master/.github/workflows/python-package-ubuntu.yml

Many thanks to @DavidW for figuring this out.
I was able to install pySFML on Windows with Python 3.7 and Cython 0.29.
see:
https://github.com/intjelic/python-sfml/blob/master/.github/workflows/python-package-windows.yml
